# Does Cuda C++ not have tuples in device code?

Tags: cuda

```
__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    auto lamb = [](int x) {return x + 1; }; // Works.
    auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3); // Does not work.
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

NVCC has lambdas at least, but `std::make_tuple` fails to compile. Are tuples not allowed in the current version of Cuda?

Comment: cuda doesn't officially provide support for `std::*anything*` in device code

Comment: ^^Issue continues, CUDA still does not support std::make_tuple or std::forward_tuple (even in Host code)

Comment: @RobertCrovella In CUDA 7/8 and later, there are exceptions like std::move, std::forward, std::initializer_list, and std::make_index_sequence. But they are the exception rather than the rule. More of std:: constexpr functions and objects can be enabled using the expt-relaxed-constexpr compilation flag in nvcc.
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/8.0/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html

Answer (score 4):

I've just tried this out and tuple metaprogramming with std:: (std::tuple, std::get, etc ...) will work in device code with C++14 and expt-relaxed-constexpr enabled (CUDA8+) during compilation (e.g. `nvcc -std=c++14 xxxx.cu -o yyyyy --expt-relaxed-constexpr`) - CUDA 9 required for C++14, but basic std::tuple should work in CUDA 8 if you are limited to that. Thrust/tuple works but has some drawbacks: limited to 10 items and lacking in some of the std::tuple helper functions (e.g. std::tuple_cat). Because tuples and their related functions are compile-time, expt-relaxed-constexpr should enable your std::tuple to "just work".

```
#include <tuple>

__global__ void kernel()
{
    auto t = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3);
    printf("%d\n",std::get<0>(t));
}

int main()
{
   kernel<<<1,1>>>();
   cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Comment: Meh. By this time I've made my own [language](https://github.com/mrakgr/The-Spiral-Language) that supports tuples, modules and first class functions inside Cuda kernels. No need to wait for Nvidia to get around to doing this.

Comment: Wow! I was *really* happy just to get basic tuple metaprogramming working ... I think you and I are on different levels! :) Looking through your repository, that's some very cool stuff

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <thrust/tuple.h>

__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    auto lamb = [](int x) {return x + 1; }; // Works.
    auto t = thrust::make_tuple(1, 2, 3);
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

I needed to get the ones from the Thrust library instead to make them work it seems. The above does compile.

Comment: is it possible untie thrust tuples?

Answer (score 2):

Support for the standard c++ library on device side is problematic for CUDA as the standard library does not have the necessary `__host__` or `__device__` annotations.

That said, both clang and nvcc do have partial support for some functionality. Usually it's limited to constexpr functions that are considered to be `__host__ __device__` if you pass `--expt-relaxed-constexpr` to nvcc (or by default in clang). Clang also has a bit more support for standard math functions. Neither supports anything that relies on C++ runtime (except for memory allocation, printf and assert) as that does not exist on device side.

So, in short -- most of the standard C++ library is unusable on device side in CUDA, though things do slowly improve as more and more functions in the standard library become `constexpr`.

Comment: The comment about constexpr is interesting as it is very similar to how I get good language interop in Spiral. By the way of analogy, in Spiral everything is constexpr'd (staged) by default. This will be great as at some point more suitable hardware than GPUs will arrive and I won't have to spend too much time porting due staging making the code highly generic. C++ templates are a form of staging, but done extremely poorly.

Comment: In case someone's interested, there's an ongoing conversation about adding better CUDA (and other accelerator) support in libc++: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/libcxx-dev/2018-December/000092.html

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, CUDA itself does not offer a device-side-capable version of `std::tuple`. However, I have a full tuple implementation as part of my [`cuda-kat` library](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat/tree/development) (still very much under initial development at the time of writing). thrust's tuple class is limited in the following senses:

1. Limited to 10 tuple elements.
2. Recursively expands templated types for every tuple element.
3. No/partial support for rvalues (e.g. in `get()`)

The tuple implementation in `cuda-kat` is an adaptation of the [EASTL](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL) tuple, which in turn is an adaptation of the LLVM project's libc++ tuple. Unlike the EASTL's, however, it is C++11-compatible, so you don't have to have the absolute latest CUDA version. It is possible to extract only the tuple class from the library with oh, I think 4 files or so, if you need just that.