# Making a two parameter-pack function work in C++

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am looking for a function that takes a couple of functions (e.g., callbacks) and their parameters, then run them with their given parameters. Input functions can have different number of parameters with various type. Please see below example code.

**The following code does not compile and gives me a compilation error (on both `gcc` and `clang` with `-std=c++17` compiler flag).**

What I am trying to understand is this:

1. Whether it is legal to have two parameter packs on a function?
2. How compiler knows where to split parameters between two packs?

My 2nd question comes from the fact that in my use case, I am forwarding those parameter packs to other functions further down our software stack. So, at some point, I am consuming one of them, but rerouting the other function (with its parameters) to another function.

**Please keep in mind that the functions/lambdas might not be in the same header file as the `runFuncs` function might be.**

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Func1, typename Func2, 
          typename... Func1Args,
          typename... Func2Args>
void runFuncs(Func1 f1, Func2 f2, Func1Args&&... f1Args, Func2Args&&... f2Args) {

    std::cout << f1(std::forward<Func1Args>(f1Args)...) << std::endl;
    std::cout << f2(std::forward<Func2Args>(f2Args)...) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    auto lam1 = [](int a, float b) { 
        return a * b; 
    };

    auto lam2 = [](std::string a, int n, float c) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << ":::" << a << ":::" << n << ":::" << c << ":::";
        return ss.str();
    };

    runFuncs(lam1, lam2, 2, 3.4f, "some_string", 555, 7.7f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could just use a single parameter pack. It would require you to determine the number of arguments in `f1` and to split the parameter pack accordingly. There is no way to tell the compiler and no way for the compiler to deduce where one parameter pack starts and where it ends.

Comment: The thing is that in this particular case, I am providing the parameters explicitly. So, at least, in this particular case, I am expecting the compiler to see that the first lambda has 2 and the second one has 3 parameters.

Comment: The compiler has no reason to assume there is any correlation between the parameter packs, and the arguments `f1` and `f2`. It never inspects the body of the function to try to deduce the template arguments. It is limited to considering the call site only.

Comment: Thanks! So, I was hoping that compiler will consume the parameter as they come in. So, the first param goes to `lam1` , the 2nd one goes to `lam1`, the 3rd one goes to `lam2`, and so on. Thanks again, François.

Answer (score -1):

You could write for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename Func1, typename Func2, 
          typename... Func1Args,
          typename... Func2Args,
          typename ArgsForFunc1 = std::tuple<Func1Args...>,
          typename ArgsForFunc2 = std::tuple<Func2Args...>
>
void runFuncs(Func1 f1, Func2 f2, ArgsForFunc1 args1, ArgsForFunc2 args2)
{
    
    std::cout << std::apply(f1, args1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::apply(f2, args2) << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    auto lam1 = [](int a, float b) { 
        return a * b; 
    };

    auto lam2 = [](std::string a, int n, float c) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << ":::" << a << ":::" << n << ":::" << c << ":::";
        return ss.str();
    };

    runFuncs(
        lam1,
        lam2,
        std::make_tuple(2, 3.4f),
        std::make_tuple("some_string", 555, 7.7f)
    );

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for rearranging the code Bernd! But, in my use case, I might not be able to use `tuple` because I might use `f1` in a CUDA kernel.

Comment: Maybe that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742242/does-cuda-c-not-have-tuples-in-device-code.
Usually tuple is implemented as chained template it should work on CUDA, too.

Comment: btw.: maybe it would be better to use std::forward_as_tuple for standard c++...